# How to add Google Maps Waypoints in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google Maps Directions Waypoints using `@react-google-maps/api` library to show the directions between starting and ending points. 
With mock data coordinates it seems to work, but not with the data coming from the `api/json` file.
Here is the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-maps-api-directions-service-forked-jvlhv?file=/src/App.js:2215-2341)
And the code below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  DirectionsRenderer,
  DirectionsService,
  GoogleMap,
  LoadScript,
  Marker
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

const containerStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "900px"
};

const center = {
  lat: 51.4332,
  lng: 7.6616
};

const options = {
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
  fullscreenControl: true,
  maxZoom: 17
};

export default function App({ parks }) {
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState();

  const directionsCallback = React.useCallback((response) => {
    console.log(response);

    if (response !== null) {
      if (response.status === "OK") {
        console.log("response", response);
        setDirections(response);
      } else {
        console.log("response: ", response);
      }
    }
  }, []);

//destination
  const destinationPark = parks.features.find(
    (park) => park.properties.id === 28007
  );
//origin
  const originPark = parks.features.find(
    (park) => park.properties.id === 35299
  );
  const google = window.google;


 // data to add as waypoints
 const waypointsParks = parks.features.filter(
    (park) => park.properties.id !== 28007 && park.properties.id !== 35299
  );

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={google_api_key}>
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={6}
          options={options}
        >
          <Marker
            position={{
              lat: parseFloat("52.50920109083271"),
              lng: parseFloat("13.416411897460808")
            }}
          />
          )
          <DirectionsService
            callback={directionsCallback}
            options={{
              destination: `${destinationPark.properties.coordinates[1]}, ${destinationPark.properties.coordinates[0]}`,
              origin: `${originPark.properties.coordinates[1]}, ${originPark.properties.coordinates[0]}`,
              travelMode: "DRIVING"
              // waypoints: [
              //   {
              //     location: new google.maps.LatLng(
              //       52.596714626379296,
              //       14.70278827986568
              //     )
              //   },
              //   {
              //     location: new google.maps.LatLng(
              //       52.56193313494678,
              //       11.52648542963747
              //     )
              //   }
              // ]
            }}
          />
          <DirectionsRenderer
            options={{
              directions: directions
            }}
          />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the failure is the following based upon codesandbox log.

> Directions request returned no results.

Your application must handle the case where no results are found.

If you feel like this is a mistake, please provide a simplified example with just the origin, destination, waypoints, etc that you believe should return a result.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated my question adding the data which needs to be as waypoint.